# String to date format java

Tags: java, android

I have this `String date="2021-04-25T18:54:18"` and i should to format like that: HH:mm ,dd mmm yyyy

I tried this

```
String date="2021-04-25T18:54:18";
 Date format= null;
    try {
        format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm, yyyy-MM-dd'T", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(date);
        holder.tvDate.setText(format.toString());

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But does not work

Comment: Are you using a pattern that matches your desired output for parsing input of a differnent format? I think you need 2 different ones...

Comment: *"i should to format like that: HH:mm ,dd mmm yyyy"* but then you give format "HH:mm, yyyy-MM-dd'T". Note that **`HH:mm ,dd mmm yyyy` != `HH:mm, yyyy-MM-dd'T`**. Note especially that the second is bad because it has that `'T` at the end, with an unmatched apostrophe.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: For your future questions please know that for some of us a plain *But does not work* is our favourite aversion in Stack Overflow questions. You should paste any error message and/or stack trace into your question, or any wrong output you are getting. This will give us a lot more precision, make it a lot easier to help you and spare you of some downvotes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The legacy date-time API (`java.util` date-time types and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat`) are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to `java.time`, the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup> .

**Using modern date-time API:**

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strDateTime = "2021-04-25T18:54:18";
        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(strDateTime);

        DateTimeFormatter dtfOutput = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm ,dd MMM yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
        String output = dtfOutput.format(ldt);
        System.out.println(output);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
18:54 ,25 Apr 2021
```

Learn more about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

**Using the legacy API:**

You need two formatters: one for input pattern and one for output pattern. You didn't need two formatters in the case of the modern API because the modern API is based on [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Dates) and your date-time string is already in this format.

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        String strDateTime = "2021-04-25T18:54:18";
        SimpleDateFormat sdfInput = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
        Date date = sdfInput.parse(strDateTime);

        SimpleDateFormat sdfOutput = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm ,dd MMM yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
        String output = sdfOutput.format(date);
        System.out.println(output);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
18:54 ,25 Apr 2021
```

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You are missing 1 step. `SimpleDateFormat` can only parse dates in the format you specify.
You are trying to parse a "yyyy-MM-dd ..." based string into the "HH:mm ..." date. This will not work.

First convert your "yyyy-MM-dd" date string into a Date.
Then, format that Date into the String you need

```
String input = "2021-04-25T18:54:18";
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(input);
String output = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm, yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH).format(date);
```

Comment: `SimpleDateFormat` is part of the terrible date-time classes originally bundled with the earliest versions of Java. These were years ago supplanted by the *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. Suggesting these legacy classes in 2021 is poor advice. See modern solution in the [Answer by Avinash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67257530/642706).

Comment: Agreed. Alltough i prefer to explain the concept in terms of the original question, instead of making the assumption it's easy to switch to the new apis.

Comment: Actually it *is* easy to mix in use of *java.time* within an existing app. No need to “switch”. The classes are built into Java 8 and later, and Android 26 and later. For earlier Android, most of the functionality is available in the latest tooling via “API desugaring”. For the now end-of-life’d Java 6 & 7, the *ThreeTen-Backport* library can be added to a project.